Intuitionistic set-theoretic geology
Work in ZF, if there are proper class many supercompact cardinals, then all grounds are uniformly definable. Hence under reasonable assumption, we can have choiceless set-theoretic geology.
But can we go further?

Are all Without-$\sf LEM$ grounds of $V$ uniformly definable? (Suppose there are proper class many supercompact cardinals)
What is the connection between Intuitionistic Set-theoretic Geology & Heyting-valued Models/presheaves?
Can We have computational interpretation of Intuitionistic Set-theoretic Geology?


This is a nice question but given the state of knowledge about inner models in constructive set theory (i.e., there is at least no published resolution of whether $\neg \mathsf{LEM}$ implies $V=L$ over $\mathsf{IZF}$) and the state of research regarding large cardinals (i.e., Mahlos have been looked at and I believe some people are looking at measurables), I feel pretty confident in saying that we're nowhere near having the kind of clear picture that would be needed to address this question.

@JamesEHanson Richard Matthews proved in his thesis (Theorem 5.5.1) that $\mathsf{IZF}$ is consistent with $\mathrm{Ord}\neq \mathrm{Ord}\cap L$, so $\mathsf{IZF}+\lnot\mathsf{LEM}+V\neq L$ is consistent.

@HanulJeon Ah that's news to me. Thank you for letting me know.

I am unsure if the notion of ground makes sense in a constructive setting. A set-theoretic universe without LEM is quite wild: For example, ordinals need not be linearly ordered, and the powerset of 2 can be uncountable (in the sense that there is no onto function from $\omega$.) I also have not seen any materials considering a generic extension of a universe without LEM, even on materials considering intuitionistic forcing.
